# How doe an addEventListenerDocument work?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, sdk, adobe-indesign

i'm curently working on a indesign extension in flex and as3. I can get my head around something, the following:

```
addEventListenerDocument    ()  method
public function addEventListenerDocument(eventTypeParam:String = null, handlerParam:Object = null, capturesParam:Boolean = false):EventListener
```

I'm using this as following:

```
document.addEventListenerDocument(DocumentEvent.AFTER_SAVE, afterSaveHandler);
```

and then the following function

```
private function afterSaveHandler(e:DocumentEvent):void {
    trace("test");
}
```

This isnt working. I get an error that i should ad a File or javascript function instead of a Function.

Can someone please explain me how i can get this working?

More info about the event [here](http://cssdk.host.adobe.com/sdk/1.5/docs/WebHelp/references/csawlib/com/adobe/indesign/Document.html#addEventListenerDocument%28%29)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The help you included contains the info although I admit it's not obvious while reading it :

> handlerParam:Object (default = null) — (Object) The event handler. Can accept: File or JavaScript Function

You may find interest in reading this cookbook :
http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Communicating_between_JavaScript_and_the_Creative-17383.html

Good luck ;)